# compiler can't find file on cifs/Samba share

Tags: compiling

I am unable to compile LaTeX files whenever they are on a particular network drive. I am using ubuntu lucid and mount a samba share in fstab like so:

```
//domain.com/me$ /home/me/H_DRIVE cifs credentials=/home/me/.smbpasswd,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

When I try to compile any file on this share with latex or pdflatex I
get the message:

```
~/H_DRIVE$ pdflatex foo
----------------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `foo'.
<*> lecture2

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

The file is certainly there, I can edit it etc. The same file compiles
fine locally. Is this a known issue? I couldn't find out much about
this, but it seems it may be because of [the size of the filesystem](https://www.opencsw.org/mantis/view.php?id=4097)
(no idea, but it must be pretty big) or [because of cifs/samba](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1772452).